# Logic - Sets of statements

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Question: Let $\alpha$ be a statement and let $\Delta, \Gamma$ be sets of statements such that $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$. Prove that if $\Gamma \models \alpha$ then $\Delta \models \alpha$ ($\models$ is the tautological implication in case the symbols are different)

In my book, the proof goes as so:

Assuming $\Gamma \models \alpha$, we will look at the truth values of each statement in $\Delta$ such that it is $\text{True}$. Given $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$ and in this case, we already know that each statement of $\Gamma$ is true. Because $\Gamma \models \alpha$, it means that $\alpha$ is true, and thus $\Delta \models \alpha$

This sounds ridiculous, I don't get it:

Who said every statement in $\Gamma$ is true?!
Furthermore, I can think of a lot of sets such that $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$ and $\Gamma \models \alpha$ but $\Delta \not \models  \alpha$ - Maybe add to $\Gamma$ a statement such that it is True when $\alpha$ is False (And this will be our $\Delta$)?

Example:

$$ \alpha = A \vee B$$
$$\Gamma = \{A,B\} \subseteq \Delta = \{A,B, \neg A\}$$

It indeed holds that $\Gamma \models \alpha$ However writing the truth table:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A& B & \neg A & A \vee B \\ \hline
1 &1 &0 &1\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
0 & 1 &1 &1\\ \hline
0 & 0 &1 &0\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

Clearly $A \models \alpha$ and $B \models \alpha$ however, $\neg A \not \models \alpha$ Because of the fourth line, where $\neg A$ is True, $\alpha$ is false!

I really don't understand the proof, nor the actual question because it seems like it is not true.. Is it? I would appreciate your kind help, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this statement is true. Remember, for something to be a model of $\Gamma$, it has to satisfy all sentences in $\Gamma$. So when we extend $\Gamma$ to the bigger set $\Delta$, any model of $\Delta$ will still be a model of $\Gamma$, as it must satisfy all sentences in $\Delta$ so particularly all sentences in $\Gamma$.

> Who said every statement in Γ is true?! Furthermore, I can think of a lot of sets such that Γ⊆Δ and Γ⊨α but Δ⊭α - Maybe add to Γ a statement such that it is True when α is False (And this will be our Δ)?

Recall we say $\Gamma\models\alpha$ if $\alpha$ holds in any model of $\Gamma$. If $\Gamma$ included a falsehood, there could be no model of $\Gamma$, so we'd vacuously have $\Gamma\models \alpha$. Similarly, if we added a statement like "$\neg \alpha$" to $\Gamma$ to get our $\Delta$ (as you'd suggest), we'd know any model of $\Delta$ would have to satisfy $\neg \alpha$. But it would still satisfy $\alpha$, as its still a model of $\Gamma$. So any model of $\Delta$ would model a contradiction, which is absurd, so again $\Delta$ would have no model and $\Delta\models\alpha$ would be vacuously true.

Comment: What about: $\alpha = A \vee B, ~~ \Gamma = \{A,B\}, ~~ \Delta = \{A,B, \sim A\}$
We know that $\Gamma \models \alpha$ and $\Gamma \subseteq \Delta$ but, if we write the truth table of $A \vee B$ and $\sim A$ we would find a line where $\sim A$ is $\text{True}$ but $A \vee B$ is $\text{False}$ (When $A=F, B=F$)

Comment: Again, $\Delta$ contains a contradiction, so there are no models of $\Delta$ and we say $\Delta\models \alpha$ vacuously ($\alpha$ holds in every model of $\Delta$ for sure if $\Delta$ has no models to begin with). It doesn't really make sense to talk about the truth table for $\Delta$, because $A\in\Delta$ implies $A$ should be true in the truth table, but ${\sim}A\in \Delta$ implies $A$ should be false in the truth table, so we can't consistently choose truth values in the first place.